# Why Layout is adjusting (scroll) upside when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout, android-constraintlayout

How to prevent scroll on edittext focus. Please give me a right path if you aware of constraint or fragment.[image]

Note: 1. I have two fragments.
      2. I am not using any kind of scroll view anywhere.
      3. I am using constraint layout for UI-design.

Workflow:

1. First fragment: i am replacing first

   FragmentManager fragmentManager 
           =MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, first_fragment);
           ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

   2. Second fragment: i am adding this fragment like

   FragmentManager fragment= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionlogin = fragment.beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransactionlogin.add(R.id.fragment_container, second_fragment,"tag");
           fragmentTransactionlogin.commit();

Problem: this all are working fine but when my second fragment is open their are two edit text so when i press(focus) on that then my all layouts is moving up.

This is my second fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:rsv="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/signupcoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_login"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_fragment" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            >


            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_ver"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_hor_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_hor_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/splashMainresImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/loginTag"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_text_medium_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputUserEmail"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputUserEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/mediumheight"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_text_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputUserPassword"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <dk.eatmore.rns.myutils.PasswordView
                android:id="@+id/inputUserPassword"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/mediumheight"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_text_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnUserLogin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnUserLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/mediumheight"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/Login"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_text_medium_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtNewUser"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtForgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/ForgotPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_text_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewRight"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnUserLogin"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_ver" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNewUser"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/NewUser"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_text_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewLeft"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_ver"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnUserLogin" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtOR"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:text="@string/or"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_text_medium_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/facebookUserLogin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewLeft"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:alpha="0.9"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtOR"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtOR"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtNewUser"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtOR">

            </View>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewRight"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:alpha="0.9"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtOR"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtForgotPassword"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtOR"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtOR">

            </View>

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/login_buttonUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/facebookUserLogin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/mediumheight"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:text="@string/facebooklogin"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_text_medium_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/shimmer_tv"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


            <com.romainpiel.shimmer.ShimmerTextView
                android:id="@+id/shimmer_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/swipe_for_menu"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/large"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:reflectionColor="@color/black" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What did you try on your own to resolve the issue?

Comment: did you tried *adjustPan* or *adjustResize* with your *Edit Text* ?

Comment: I tried adjustPan or adjustResize in fragment but not working.

Comment: for the solution if i replace fragment instead of add fragment that time it is working fine but why it is not working on add fragment . A part from this i tried clickable false/true for frame layout issues but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please add adjustPan or adjustResize into MainActivity where you add the code of fragment. Keyboard will auto adjust the screen.